# Complete reducibility of integrable modules over symmetrizable Kac-Moody Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

I am reading the book "Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras" by Victor G Kac. This is a long question regarding my understanding of the following theorem.

In Theorem 10.7 Kac proves the complete reducibility of the integrable modules over symmetrizable Kac-Moody lie algebras. we have the following proof where he proves that if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be two primitive weights and $\lambda - \mu = \beta \in Q_+$ then $$2(\lambda+\rho \mid \beta) \ne (\beta,\beta).$$
[image]
To prove complete reproducibility, it is enough to prove the above condition in view of the following Proposition 9.9.
[image]
But the proof of the above Proposition uses the following Lemma where it is claimed that to prove a module is completely reducible it is enough to prove that for any two primitive weights $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of $V$ the inequality $\lambda \ge \mu$ implies $\lambda = \mu$.
[image]

I want to understand the proof of Theorem 10.7. I have the following questions:

1. Let $V \in \mathcal O$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ be the associated weights such that every weights in V is of the form $\lambda_i - \beta$ for some $\beta \in Q_+$ (Root lattice). Then $V^0 = \oplus_{i=1}^k V_{\lambda_i}$? ($V^0$ is defined in Lemma 9.5 given above)
2. Can theorem 10.7 be proved directly using Lemma 9.5 by proving for any two primitive weights $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of $V$ the inequality $\lambda \ge \mu$ implies $\lambda = \mu$ in $V$? Here, it is proved in multiple steps using the equation $2(\lambda+\rho,\beta) = (\beta,\beta)$. What is the problem if there are two comparable primitive weights in the complete reducibility of $V$?
3. In the proof of Proposition 9.9(b). How to show that $\Omega$ is locally finite and there exists $a \in \Bbb C$ such that $\Omega-aI$ is locally impotent.
4. What is the role of the equations $|\lambda + \rho|^2 = |\mu + \rho|^2$ and $2(\lambda+\rho,\beta) = (\beta,\beta)$ (one implies the other) (where $\lambda - \mu = \beta \in Q_+$) in the entire proof?
5. I am finding the flow of the proof a little confusing in my first reading. Anywhere else can I find a direct or an alternate proof?
6. What is the analogue of Theorem 10.7 for the case of superalgebras? Kindly share some references. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to prove (3) :

**Claim**: The Casimir element $\Omega$ preserves the weight spaces of $V$.

Proof:
    Let $v \in V_{\lambda}$. Since $\Omega$ commutes with the action of $\operatorname{lie} g$ we have $$h \cdot \Omega(v) = \Omega (h \cdot v) = \Omega(\lambda(h)(v)) = \lambda(h)(\Omega(v)).$$ This proves the claim.

**Claim**: The Casimir element $\Omega$ acts locally finite on $V$

Proof: Let $v \in V$, then $v \in \oplus_{i=1}^k V_{\lambda_i}$ for some weights $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k$ of $V$. Since the weight spaces are preserved under the action of $\Omega$, $\oplus_{i=1}^k V_{\lambda_i}$ is the required finite-dimensional $\Omega$ invariant subspace containing $v$.

**Claim**: There exists $a \in \mathbb C$ such that $\Omega - a I$ is locally nilpotent on $V$.

Proof: Since $\Omega$ acts on $V$, we can write $V = \oplus_{\alpha \in \mathbb C}V_{\alpha}$
    where the $V_{\alpha}$s are generalized eigenspaces of $\Omega$. If $v \in V_{\alpha}$ and $x \in \mathrm{lie} g$ then there exists $r > 0$ such the $(\Omega - \alpha I)^r(v) = 0$. We want to show that there exists $s>0$ such that $(\Omega - \alpha I)^s(x \cdot v) = 0$. If $v \in V$, $x,y \in \operatorname {lie} g$ and $\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb C$ then $$(y - (\alpha+\beta)I)^r(x\cdot v) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^r\binom{r}{i} = ((\text{ad }y - \beta I)^i(x))((y - \alpha I)^{r-i}(v)).$$
    Since $\Omega$ is an operator on $V$, $y$ can be replaced with $\Omega$ and we take $\beta = 0$. Then the above equation becomes 
    $$(\Omega - \alpha I)^r(x\cdot v) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^r\binom{r}{i} ((\text{ad }\Omega)^i(x))((\Omega - \alpha I)^{r-i}(v)).$$
    Since $\Omega$ is an central element, we get $(\text{ad }\Omega)^i(x)) = 0$ whenever $i>0$. Hence the above equation becomes  $$(\Omega - \alpha I)^r(x\cdot v) = (\Omega - \alpha I)^{r}(v).$$ This shows that the generalized eigenspaces $V_{\alpha}$s are $\operatorname{lie} g$-invariant. We have assumed that $V$ is indecomposable, therefore $V = V_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Please help me with Latex. Why Latex comments are not processed?

Comment: Bold texts should be included in between ** content **. Indented paragraphs seems to be interpreted as code blocks, removing them should work. Also \lie is not defined. I submitted an edit.

Comment: @QixianZhao Thank you very much for the edit.